# Is it possible to insert rendered ASP.NET controls with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dynamic, insert, label

I'm not very familiar with ASP.NET, so forgive me if I word this question poorly. We build lots of .aspx pages that include dynamic "labels" that render as plain text when viewed in the browser. For example, if the source of my .aspx contains this code:

`<p>Thanks for trying <em>{ProductName}</em>!</p>`

The page when viewed in the browser will read:

> Thanks for trying *My Company's Product*!

Now, I want to able to insert that text on the page dynamically via JavaScript. The problem is that if I have a script write that same bit of code to the page, I get this:

> Thanks for trying *{ProductName}*!

I assume this is because the page has already finished rendering before the script runs, so the dynamic label gets treated as plain text instead of rendering on the server side first.

Is there any way at all that I can do this?

Comment: ajax could be an option?

Comment: Where are you getting the actual product name from? Why wouldn't it be available when you are rendering the page?

Answer (score 0):

The .aspx scripts are server side rendered, so they are rendered at your web server and then downloaded by the user, so the user already gets a page with that values. 
On the other side, javascript is rendered at the client machine, so he downloads the script, and the browser renders the page, thats why you dont get that value show.

There are some workarounds to do that.

First, and the better one is to try ajax. That means that the javascript will do another server request to get that value and show it to the user, and that value will come from server.

Second, you can try to put these server variables on script variables or hidden html elements. That way, when you want to use that values, you can get it from the local script(javascript). It would be something like writting the value on a hidden  or hidden input " >, and recover it like 
`document.getElementById("value_id").innerHTML` or even set the javascript variables at your page, doing something like

var val = "<%=ProductName%>";

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that syntax.  I would expect something like `<%= ProductName %>` instead.  What flavor of ASP.Net are you using?  WebForms?  MVC?  Spark?

Since curly braces are integral to the JavaScript language, it is likely that JavaScript tags are not parsed for string replacement.  It would take a pretty robust parsing engine to know when the curly braces indicate a string replacement and when they are part of the JavaScript code.  If you can switch to the `<%= ProductName %>` syntax for your JavaScript, that may be the easiest.  If that's not an option or doesn't work for your situation, try putting the strings in the html, and extracting them from JavaScript.  A hidden input seems ideal:

```
<input type="hidden" id="ProductName" value="{ProductName}" />
```

You may find it doesn't work in attributes.  Fine, just use a hidden span:

```
<span class="hidden" id="ProductName">{ProductName}</span>
```

(don't forget to define a "hidden" css class to do the actual hiding: `.hidden { display: none; }`)

Get at your strings with JavaScript:

```
var productName = document.getElementById("ProductName").value;      // hidden input
var productName = document.getElementById("ProductName").innerHTML;  // hidden span
```

Comment: Both good suggestions, but unfortunately I don't think either will work in my particular case. We have tons of these labels in use across tons of sites. I can't just change the syntax suddenly, and likewise, it's impractical to insert a hidden element for every one on a page. Thanks, though - I'll give it some more thought.